# How to prepend to the url of the API root in Retrofit / Can I have two Rest Adapters?

Tags: android, android-studio, adapter, retrofit

This is how I set up my RetroFit client.

```
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
    builder.setEndpoint(Server.API_ROOT);
    builder.setExecutors(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5), new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5));
    RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
    REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(API.class);
```

However, some of the API endpoints I'm using are http://example.com/ and others are http://test.example.com/ so what should I do?

Actually, can I have 2 adapters for two different APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to implement Endpoint

Sample: 
https://medium.com/@kevintcoughlin/dynamic-endpoints-with-retrofit-a1f4229f4a8d

If you are using 2.0 beta+ , **EndPoint** is renamed to **BaseUrl**

Also, take a look at this for 2.0+ :

```
New: @Url parameter annotation allows passing a complete URL for an endpoint.
```